# Change Datepicker Date Format just on Front End

Tags: php, date, format

I purchased a plugin for Wordpress/Woocommerce that has a Datepicker.  It comes with several date formats available (i.e. mm/dd/yy, yy/mm/dd, dd/mm/yy, etc.). Is there a way on the front end to reformat the date to print out dddd, mm/dd/yy in order to add the associated weekday name (i.e. Sunday, 09/20/2020) and not just the month, day and year (i.e. 09/20/2020)?

I have tried several pieces of both php and javascript code and nothing happens.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure which plugin you're using, but I did something similar for PDF invoices & Packing Slips to convert the custom field "order_delivery_date" to a similar date format (e.g. Sunday 09/20/2020) with this:

```
<?php echo date('l m/d/Y', strtotime( $this->get_custom_field('order_delivery_date'))); ?>
```

Comment: I am using Woocommerce TM Extra Product Options.